Gradle Firebase App Distribution Properties Not Included in Build Variant
I have integrated my build.gradle with firebase app distribution. It worked well when I put the firebaseAppDistribution block inside the buildType. But I want to add the release notes based on app build variant. So I create like this:
androidComponents {
    onVariants { variant ->
        firebaseAppDistribution{
            artifactType = "APK"
            releaseNotes = "Release notes for ${variant.name} build."
        }
    }
}

this block is called after the android block.
After that I executed command ./gradlew assembleStagingGoogleDebug appDistributionUploadStagingGoogleDebug
it successfully uploaded the APK to firebase but the problem is the release notes is skipped and not uploaded to the firebase.
Uploading APK to Firebase App Distribution...
Using cached Firebase CLI credentials
Uploading the APK.
Uploaded APK successfully 200
No release notes passed in. Skipping this step.
No testers or groups passed in. Skipping this step.

How I manage to add release notes for every build variant?
